# Listen to serial port at STARTUP using java with arguments on Debian(Rasbian)

Tags: java, python, linux, daemon, startup

I've been stuck two weeks trying to figure out how to run this at startup.
I use the following chain of commands on the terminal:

```
   1. source ~/.bashrc
   2. source ~/.tinyos.sh
   3. java net.tinyos.tools.Listen -comm serial@/dev/ttyUSB0:telosb | python demo.py`
```

The third command uses java to listen to the serial port and pipes it to a python script which cleans, converts and uploads to mysql localhost.

This works fine on ssh terminal. But ive tried using nohup+update-rc.d, upstart, systemd, crontab to make it run on startup and it just wont work! When I reboot and check logs / database, its as if the command never happened. I need this to run like a daemon and continue running until shutdown.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to execute the program ? Are there are permission issues accessing / executing the script ?
Which version of debian are you running - look at upstart scripts if you are running Jesse+

I'd put those three lines in a bash script and use upstart scripts to trigger them on start. Another option is to use supervisord to make sure that your scripts run and restart if for any reason the program crashes.

Comment: I'm using rasbian. So far im using a custom sh script that has the above three commands and add the command at `sudo crontab -e` with the following line:

`@reboot screen -d my_script /home/pi/start-up-script.sh`